# I have 2 js file but the second doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have the first js file with all my things and also my buttons already created with a specified class.
In the second js file i wanted to do some events when that button with that class is clicked but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

this is my call to the first js file

```
<script src="js/tmdb/searchFilm.js"></script>
```

then on the file I create this element:

```
var td = tr.insertCell();
   var btn = document.createElement("button");   
   btn.setAttribute("type", "button"); 
   btn.setAttribute("id",ids[i]);
   btn.setAttribute("class","btnInfo");
   var t = document.createTextNode("More info");       
   btn.appendChild(t);
```

and everything is ok

but in the second  js file i have thi

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.btnInfo').click(function (event) {
          console.log("arrivato");
      });
  });
```

but if i add the script as the first one it does not work, any suggestions?

zero output on the console

Comment: My suggestion would be to post some code.  How could we possibly help you otherwise?

Comment: Define, "doesn't work"

Comment: let me get my crystal ball

Comment: yeah sorry guys @Brad

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you load the second file? Any output in the console?

Comment: no output on the console, i've loaded the second file the same way as te first

Comment: did you try outputting something to the console right after document.ready? If that works, you probably have problem with your click event, maybe wrong class name

Comment: when i output after document ready it works,but i posted the code, the class name is right no?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `event` in

```
$('.btnInfo').click(function (event) {
    console.log("arrivato");
});
```

to something else, like `e`. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be because you are adding the button dynamically and so the jquery event handlers are not attached to it.

Try adding the same event to the immediate parent that was there when the document loaded (and was not added dynamically). The events bubble up and so it should be caught by the parent element.

Instead of binding to '.btnInfo', bind it to the immediate parent